# Return different object from a method in JSON API based on conditions

Tags: java, json, spring, api, spring-mvc

In my Spring mvc application, I have a class ManagePerson , which needs to return Person or MinimalPerson ,

how can I make it return Person or MinimalPerson from getPersons() ?

ManagePerson.java

```
public class ManagePerson {

private List<Person> persons;

   public ManagePerson(List<Person> persons) {
      this.persons = persons;
   }

   public List<Person> getPersons() {
      return persons;   

   }

}
```

Person.java

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

private String name;
private Long id;

public Person(String name, Long id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Person o) {

    if(this.getId() == null) {
        return -1;
    } 

    if(this.getName() != null && o.getName() == null) return -1;
    if(this.getName() == null && o.getName() != null) return 1;
    if(!this.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(o.getName())) {
        return this.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getName());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

}

MinimalPerson.java

```
public class MinimalPerson() {
  private Person person;

  public MinimalPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.person.getName();     
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you add the condition which decide what to return in getPersons method?

Comment: Since its JSON api response, I want the semantics in JSON response to always have 'persons' and depending on whether i want to expose Person or MinimalPerson, i want to decide that.

Comment: I don't see any relation to Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Person Extend MinimalPerson and then your ManagePerson class would have to be:

```
public class ManagePerson<T extends MinimalPerson> {

  private List<T> persons;

    public ManagePerson(List<T> persons) {
       this.persons = persons;
    }

    public List<T> getPersons() {
       return persons;   

    }

}
```

This makes use of Java's generics

One important thing to note here is the fact that with Java generics, `<T extends MinimalPerson>` will match both Person and MinimalPerson.

Comment: This sounds good. But the problem is Person implements Comparable, and overrides compareTo , and in ManagePerson i do Collections.sort , how can i do Collections.sort now ?